# Python multiprocessing OverflowError 4GiB limit on small arrays

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to use multiprocessing on my code:

```
def get_units_mean_waveform(self, unit_ids: list, ms_before: float=2, ms_after: float=2, max_spikes_per_unit=None, max_channels_per_waveforms=None, n_jobs: int=1):
    if n_jobs == 1:
        return [self.get_unit_mean_waveform(unit_id, ms_before, ms_after, max_spikes_per_unit, max_channels_per_waveforms) for unit_id in unit_ids]

    with Pool(processes=n_jobs) as pool:
        mean_waveforms = []
        res = []
        for unit_id in unit_ids:
            res.append(pool.apply_async(self.get_unit_mean_waveform, (unit_id, ms_before, ms_after, max_spikes_per_unit, max_channels_per_waveforms)))
        for i in range(len(res)):
            mean_waveforms.append(res[i].get())

        return mean_waveforms


def get_unit_mean_waveform(self, unit_id: int, ms_before: float=2, ms_after: float=2, max_spikes_per_unit=None, max_channels_per_waveforms=None):
    mean_wvf = np.mean(self.get_unit_waveforms(unit_id, ms_before, ms_after, max_spikes_per_unit, max_channels_per_waveforms), axis=0, dtype=np.float32)
    print("{0:.2f} kiB".format(mean_wvf.nbytes/1024))
    print("{0} of {1}".format(mean_wvf.shape, mean_wvf.dtype))
    return mean_wvf
```

My output is the following:

```
2.36 kiB
(5, 121) of float32
2.36 kiB
(5, 121) of float32
2.36 kiB
(5, 121) of float32
2.36 kiB
(5, 121) of float32
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 61, in <module>
    wvfs = data.get_units_mean_waveform([20, 21, 22, 23, 24], max_spikes_per_unit=20000, max_channels_per_waveforms=5, n_jobs=2)
  File "/export/home1/users/nsr/wyngaard/Documents/NeurAlgo-ExtracellularAnalysis/phy_data.py", line 186, in get_units_mean_waveform
    mean_waveforms.append(res[i].get())
  File "/users/nsr/wyngaard/.conda/envs/kilosort/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/users/nsr/wyngaard/.conda/envs/kilosort/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 431, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "/users/nsr/wyngaard/.conda/envs/kilosort/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/users/nsr/wyngaard/.conda/envs/kilosort/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
OverflowError: cannot serialize a bytes object larger than 4 GiB
```

I do not understand why I have an error with the `4 GiB` limit, as I only return the mean which is about `2 kiB`.

The result of `self.get_unit_waveforms` is an array `(20000, 5, 121) of int16`, which from my calculation should be around `23.08 MiB`.

Comment: Can you print shape of result of calling `self.get_unit_waveforms()` inside body of `get_unit_mean_waveform()`? I.e. do `print(self.get_unit_waveforms(.....).shape)`. What does it print?

Comment: It prints (5, 121) for all unit_id.

Comment: maybe the problem is how you start your `multiprocessing` script? Do you know that initial multiprocessing root script should be run under `if __name__ == '__main__':`? Because all child processes should skip root-script code.

Comment: The file I'm calling is main.py, which doesn't import multiprocessing. The code I showed is in another file which is just a class with different methods I'm calling from the main file. So I don't see where the `if __name__ == "__main__"` would go in this case?

Comment: Filename is not important, important what you have inside main.py, look [at sample code here](https://tio.run/##XYxBCoMwEEX3nmJ2JkXcSDcF79AbDKNNdMBMhiRSPH2quOtbPT6Pr0dZowy1ctCYCoR9K6wpzi5nlqX5OA/eUAeTfTVwklzZkwDBA6aGPSAKBYcI4wgtYiAWxPZuv1zW/8f@HeNmLFAGPe0OLzSxFHNtPaluB1I@ZDa@AzN08LS2X1wx1tb6Aw). As you can see I have `if __name__ == '__main__':` block, all pool processing code should be inside this block, it is wrong not to have `if __name__ == '__main__':` block inside any multiprocessing-based script!

Comment: It is [WRONG to do like here](https://tio.run/##XYsxDsMgDAB3XuHRrhBL1KWv6A8qkkCCRIwFjipeT1N16013w0nXvfA0RjqkVIXjzJqkliW0lngza4gQ0VuY6WHgogY9K4OHG8zmnXT/X9yzlIwEvoFc9rukJlb8tvMiub9867xgtICThTuR24Ii0Rgf) where there is no `if __name__ == '__main__':`. See my comment above how to do right.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I added `if __name__ == "__main__":` in my `main.py`, which is where the call to `get_units_mean_waveform()` takes place, but this 4 GiB OverflowError still persists.